# SSL: How to handle multiple clients with separate keys connecting to the same port?

Tags: java, ssl, x509certificate, certificate-store

Another legacy support problem here!
We have a server multiple clients network where each component has a self signed certificate and is added to the server/client's trust store. We are not using a Certificate Authority here.
Now our problem is that we need to upgrade all the certificates for better security. The new clients will come with newer certificates and even the server will have new certificates.
Our problem is how to handle the old clients. Upgrading keystores of our old clients is the last resort.

Things that won't work:

1. Adding both the new and old certificates in server truststore: Even the clients are authenticating the servers and the server certificate will not be present in the client truststore.
2. Using new port for the new clients: We considered using new ports for new clients and continuing the old ports for old clients but the problem is that there are multiple applications which are facing this problem so we will have to search for multiple new ports which are not being used by other products.

FWIW: The servers are in Java and the clients are in C++

**EDIT after EJP's answer**
I am probably asking a very dumb question here but just wanted to be sure. There is absolutely no way to edit the SSL Context of a socket once it is bound. Correct?
Also, can we choose the server certificate to be used during the handshake? I know of `chooseClientAlias()` and `chooseServerAlias()` methods but here we don't know which certificate to use till the client Hello message is sent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leaving aside using different ports:

1. (1) will work as far as the server is concerned with the client certificates.
2. *Nothing* will work in terms of getting old clients to recognize the new server certificate, other than upgrading the client truststores.

This is why you should have used a CA, even an internal one, and why you should **absolutely not** make the same mistake again. If the clients had trusted the CA instead of a self-signed server certificate directly, you would not now have this problem, and you won't have it in future, however many times you upgrade the certificates, until the CA certificate expires, which should take 20 years.

And while you're at it, make sure you build in a way to update client truststores.

> There is absolutely no way to edit the SSL Context of a socket once it is bound. Correct?

There is no way to edit the `SSLContext` once it is *initialized*, which precedes creation of sockets, let alone binding them. Hmm, maybe you could reload the `KeyManager` and `TrustManager` and just not tell the `SSLContext`, but I'm not saying it would (or wouldn't) work.

> Also, can we choose the server certificate to be used during the handshake?

Yes, that's what the `KeyManager` interface is for, specifically `chooseServerAlias()`.

> I know of `chooseClientAlias()` and `chooseServerAlias()` methods but here we don't know which certificate to use till the client Hello message is sent.

`chooseServerAlias` isn't called until the `ClientHello` has been received.

Comment: I agree with your point on using a CA. I have updated the question with one more thread that is being discussed. Can you answer that as well?

Comment: I will try the chooseServerAlias() method. I think that should solve our problem. Use the old keys for old agents and new keys for new servers. At least till we have a CA architecture up.